# Livewire component not updating

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a simple component:

```php
<input type="text" wire:model="search">
{{ $search }}
```

I load this like this:

```php
@livewire('searchbar')
```

And this is my class:

```php
class Searchbar extends Component
{
    public $search;

    public $results = [];

    public function updatedSearch()
    {
        info($this->search);
        $this->results = Client::search($this->search)->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.searchbar', [
            'results' => $this->results,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I type into the input field, the `info()` logs the correct value but in the view, the the `{{ $search }}` gets not updated. When I use `protected $queryString = ['search'];` the URL get's updated correctly as well and if I would use `dd()` instead of `info()` I'd see the view updating with the dd.

Why is the $search not updating in the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your component. Make sure your Blade view only has [ONE root element](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#returning-blade).

```
<div>
   <input type="text" wire:model="search">
   {{ $search }}
</div>
```

Comment: Shame on me. A core thing of Livewire.... Damn, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, inside livewire render, you do not need to send variables.

This will be sufficient.

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.searchbar');
    }
```

You already declared $results as public variable, just like $search.
Livewire will know when the content of those variables are updated.

And now please try again.

$search should be automatically updated based on any text you inserted in input text with wire:model attribute.

Comment: Not related to my issue resolution but very good comment. Thank you! I'll update it

Comment: Aha, did not even know that your component was not inside single div .... i thought this was the problem origin ... Have fun with livewire